# Flag Documentation Example As Duplicate

Tags: feature-request, documentation

The ability to flag examples as duplicates (or subsets) of other examples would be helpful. For example, in [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim) there is an [Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vim/879/introduction-to-vim/2965/installation) example as well as a separate [Install on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vim/879/introduction-to-vim/4886/installation-on-osx) example.

Thusfar, I have used custom flags to indicate where this is an issue.

Comment: I agree that this is an issue. I wanted to mark [one example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iWMhU.png) as unnecessary, as a duplicate of another one, or as a good candidate for merging, and there's really no "request improvement" option that fits that.