# Documentation - Close as duplicate

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Today I tried to close as dup a question using one of the examples of the documentation, and it seems not be possible. Would it make sense to have such feature ?

Comment: Though idea sounds good, But I think as it is still in beta, we should consider it only after it goes stable.

Comment: Also cross references are not possible.

Comment: @rene I was thinking about cross "topics" like using JSON in Java vs. Android. It should be accessible at both places, but there should be no duplicates.

Comment: @rene do have a link?

Comment: @rekire [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329091/how-should-we-handle-duplicate-documentation-examples) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329014/flag-documentation-example-as-duplicate) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329037/add-duplicate-as-rejection-reason-for-proposed-changes)